# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE with docker-compose of a Laravel app

Tags: laravel, docker

I have a Laravel / VueJS app that I am trying to dockerize.

At the end of the Dockerfile, I have

```
CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=80
```

my docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    image: xoco/kendozone:local-1.0.1
    ports:
      - "8181:80"
```

When I run:

```
 docker-compose up
```

I get:

```
Recreating local_app_1 ... done
Attaching to local_app_1
app_1  | [03-May-2018 18:20:21] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1
app_1  | [03-May-2018 18:20:21] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
```

that seems to be ok

But when I try to access it on

```
localhost:8181
```

I get a ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Any idea how to fix it ?

EDIT: Add Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm
LABEL version="1.0.0"

ENV node_version 8.4.0
ENV npm_version 5.7.1
ENV NVM_DIR /.nvm
ENV APP_DIR="/var/www"
ENV APP_PORT="80"
ENV DOCKER_FOLDER="docker/local"

RUN echo "deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stretch main " >> /etc/apt/sources.list \
&& apt-get update -y 
RUN apt-get install -y openssl zip unzip git gcc make automake \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libmagickwand-dev vim --no-install-recommends
RUN apt-get purge --auto-remove -y g++ \
&& apt-get clean \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
&& docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql mbstring zip -j$(nproc) iconv  -j$(nproc) gd

WORKDIR $APP_DIR
COPY . $APP_DIR

RUN mkdir -p $APP_DIR/resources/assets/less/_main_full \
&& touch $APP_DIR/resources/assets/less/_main_full/main.less \
&& touch $APP_DIR/database/sqlite.db \
&& mv $DOCKER_FOLDER/.env.local .env \
&& chown -R www-data:www-data $APP_DIR

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN composer install --no-interaction

RUN mkdir -p $NVM_DIR && chown -R www-data:www-data $NVM_DIR
RUN  curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.8/install.sh | bash \
&& [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" \
&& nvm install ${node_version}

ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/v$node_version/lib/node_modules
ENV PATH $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v$node_version/bin:$PATH

RUN npm install --save-exact imagemin-pngquant@5.0.*
RUN npm install
RUN npm run production
RUN php artisan key:generate
RUN php artisan migrate --seed 
CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=$APP_PORT
```

Comment: Please provide your `Dockerfile`. It is hard to say what's the issue without it.

Comment: my question was updated with dockerfile